# Modifier .weight() not setted automatically in column and can't add

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i am new to jetpack compose and also have some experience with flutter so when move to compose its a little bit similar to flutter declarative UI style but i don't quite understand
like in flutter when i want some widget to expanded and want it to take full available space we can use `Exapanded` widget and if i use this in Column its automatically add `flex` of 1 or `weight` in terms of jetpack compose so i want to do same thing in jetpack compose but its seems like jetpack column not automatically and `weight` to its children and also i cant add
`Modifier.weight(1f)` in `Card` of `NetworkCardComposable` so i have to pass Modifier from as Parameter and in when using this Compoasable in columns this `Modifier.weight(1f)` have to set through parameter which is odd i think.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 500, heightDp = 200)
@Composable
fun NetworkCardComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(1f)
            .padding(16.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.jazz_color_primary)
    ) {
        Row {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(2f)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(8.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.jazz_logo),
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(2f)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Bundles & Offers",
                    color = Color.White,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h5.fontSize,
                )
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(56.dp),
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ChevronRight,
                    tint = Color.White,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun networkCard() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        NetworkCardComposable(Modifier.weight(1f))
        NetworkCardComposable(Modifier.weight(1f))
        NetworkCardComposable(Modifier.weight(1f))
        NetworkCardComposable(Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
}
```

all thought i have acheive my desired layout but if there is any better approach to this please answer

Comment: Your code is correct. You can apply the `weight` modifier in a `ColumnScope`. The only alternative if you want to use the `NetworkCardComposable` **only** in a `Column` is to define something like `fun ColumnScope.NetworkCardComposable()`.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what i want

Comment: using `ColumnScope.NetworkCardCompoasble` making preview not woking is there any fix for that issue

Answer (score -1):

Jetpack Compose aims at providing the maximum control over the UI. Hence, by default, the elements of a container like column default to wrap content. If you want them to occupy Max available space of the container, the proper way to do it is using `Modifier.fillMaxSize()`

As far as weights are concerned, if you do not specify then explicitly while adding more than one elements inside a container, the weights are calculated accordingly, based on the minimum required dimensions, (i.e., again, wrapContentSize ())